# unable to detect camera on raspberry pi 4 b (bullseye)

Tags: camera, config.txt, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye

I have my camera module connected and have also tried `sudo apt-get update` and `apt-get update` as well but my os is already up to date.

But when I try `vcgencmd get-camera` it gives an output like
Output: `supported=0 detected=0, libcamera interfaces=0`

Here is my config file :

```
# For more options and information see
# http://rpf.io/configtxt
# Some settings may impact device functionality. See link above for details

# uncomment if you get no picture on HDMI for a default "safe" mode
#hdmi_safe=1

# uncomment the following to adjust overscan. Use positive numbers if console
# goes off screen, and negative if there is too much border
#overscan_left=16
#overscan_right=16
#overscan_top=16
#overscan_bottom=16

# uncomment to force a console size. By default it will be display's size minus
# overscan.
#framebuffer_width=1280
#framebuffer_height=720

# uncomment if hdmi display is not detected and composite is being output
hdmi_force_hotplug=1

# uncomment to force a specific HDMI mode (this will force VGA)
hdmi_group=1
hdmi_mode=76

# uncomment to force a HDMI mode rather than DVI. This can make audio work in
# DMT (computer monitor) modes
#hdmi_drive=2

# uncomment to increase signal to HDMI, if you have interference, blanking, or
# no display
config_hdmi_boost=4

# uncomment for composite PAL
#sdtv_mode=2

#uncomment to overclock the arm. 700 MHz is the default.
#arm_freq=800

# Uncomment some or all of these to enable the optional hardware interfaces
dtparam=i2c_arm=on
#dtparam=i2s=on
dtparam=spi=on

# Uncomment this to enable infrared communication.
#dtoverlay=gpio-ir,gpio_pin=17
#dtoverlay=gpio-ir-tx,gpio_pin=18

# Additional overlays and parameters are documented /boot/overlays/README

# Enable audio (loads snd_bcm2835)
dtparam=audio=on

# Automatically load overlays for detected cameras
#start_x=1
camera_auto_detect=1
# Automatically load overlays for detected DSI displays
display_auto_detect=1

# Enable DRM VC4 V3D driver
#dtoverlay=vc4-kms-v3d
max_framebuffers=2

# Disable compensation for displays with overscan
disable_overscan=1

[cm4]
# Enable host mode on the 2711 built-in XHCI USB controller.
# This line should be removed if the legacy DWC2 controller is required
# (e.g. for USB device mode) or if USB support is not required.
otg_mode=1

[all]

[pi4]
dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d
# Run as fast as firmware / board allows
arm_boost=1

[all]
enable_uart=1
dtoverlay=w1-gpio
gpu_mem=256
```

Comment: Have you got the blue side of the cable facing the Ethernet port?

Comment: No, I have checked the the connections are correct.
but I found that a file called dt-blob.bin has something to do with it , and i am unable to figure out what to do

Comment: okay so there is a new kind of error
when i enable the legacy camera option , it gives the output supported=1 detected=1, but when i change the config.txt and add camera_auto_detect=1 it gives the output supported=0 detected=0 , so i am unable to use libcamera with this os(fully updated).

Comment: Have you updated the **firmware** also?

Comment: yes i have updated the firmware as well